# ImportError: No module named 'Shapes' when running Python scripts and tests

Tags: python, module, pytest, importerror, project-structure

**Description:**

- I'm encountering an ImportError issue in my Python project related to module imports. The project structure is as follows:

```
C:.
├───Shapes
│   │   Circle.py
│   │   Rectangle.py
│   │   Shape.py
│   │   __init__.py
│           
├───tests
│   │   conftest.py
│   │   test_circle.py
│   │   test_rectangle.py
```

- In `Circle.py` and `Rectangle.py`, I'm getting the error "No module named 'Shapes'" when trying to run the scripts. Additionally, when attempting to run tests in the `tests` directory, I encounter the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shapes'".

```
# Circle.py
from Shapes.Shape import Shape  # Importing the Shape base class
import math as Math

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius=0):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._radius = max(1, radius)

    def area(self):
        return Math.pi * Math.pow(self.radius, 2)

# ... (rest of the code)
```

```
# Rectangle.py
from Shapes.Shape import Shape  # Importing the Shape base class

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height

    @width.setter
    def width(self, width):
        self._width = width

    @height.setter
    def height(self, height):
        self._height = height

    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.width

# ... (rest of the code)
```

```
# test_circle.py
import pytest
from Shapes.Circle import Circle
import math as Math

class TestCircle:
    def setup_method(self, method):
        # Setting up the test environment
        self.circle = Circle(2)

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        # Tearing down the test environment
        pass

    def test_radius(self):
        assert self.circle.radius == 2

    def test_area(self):
        assert self.circle.area() == Math.pi * Math.pow(self.circle.radius, 2)
```

```
# test_rectangle.py
import pytest
from Shapes.Rectangle import Rectangle

def test_area():
    assert object.area() == 6  # Assuming object is an instance of Rectangle with width=2 and height=3
```

**Error Messages:**

- When running `Circle.py` or `Rectangle.py`, I get the error:

```
No module named 'Shapes'
```

- When running tests in the `tests` directory, I encounter:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shapes'`

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- I've tried adding the project root to the `sys.path` in the test files, but its not best practise and I'm looking for a cleaner solution.
- Using relative imports didn't resolve the issue just got.

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**Question:**

- How can I fix the "No module named 'Shapes'" error in my Python project structure? Is there a recommended approach to organize the project and imports?

**What I Tried:**

Attempted to run `Circle.py` and `Rectangle.py` scripts and executed tests in the `tests` directory. Explored relative imports and considered adding the project root to `sys.path`.

**Expected:**

Scripts to run without ImportError for 'Shapes'. Tests to execute successfully without "No module named 'Shapes'" error.

**Actual Result:**

Received ImportError for 'Shapes' when running scripts and `ModuleNotFoundError` in tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found the solution to the issue I was facing. The problem arises when running tests directly from the terminal using

```
pytest tests/
```

or

```
python pytest tests/
```

In these cases, pytest treats the tests/ directory as the root of the project, leading to import errors.

To resolve this, I discovered that running tests as a module with

```
python -m pytest tests/
```

Solves the problem. By using -m, I explicitly indicate that tests is a module, and now the import paths are handled correctly.